# Where does the connection to database need to be made?

Tags: python, database, tweepy

I am creating a twitter bot that searches twitter for ticker symbols. I am then sending them to a database. The problem that I have here is that the list that is getting sent is not changing.
Maybe I have to keep connecting to the database, but I can not figure out where my problem is. Can anyone figure out how to make make the list of tickers be different everytime?

```
def searchTwit():
    tweets = api.search("#stocks",count=100)
    return tweets 



print("connecting to database")
#connecting to the database
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server};"
    "Server=..............;"
    "Database=master;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = conn.cursor()

tickList=[]


def getTicker(tweets):
    for tweet in tweets:
        if "$" in tweet.text:
            x = tweet.text.split()
            for i in x:
                if i.startswith("$") and i[1].isalpha():
                    i.strip(".")
                    i.upper()
                    tickList.append(i)

# print(var_string)
def retrieveTickers():
    for i in tickList:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO master.dbo.TickerTable (TickerName) VALUES (?);', (i))
    conn.commit()

    # thing to run

print("about to do while ")

while True:
    sleep(60 - time() %60)
    print("searchtwit")
    searchTwit()
    theTweets = searchTwit()
    getTicker(theTweets)
    print("getting Tickers")
    retrieveTickers()
    print("sending tickers")
    print(tickList)
    tickList=[]
    print(tickList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a remote database or on your local machine. Define which database you want to use, so in your database server be 127.0.0.1:PORT (that means that the database is your machine) (THE PORT will change depending on which SGDB you want